# What's stripping the characters from my menu links? (ie. '?' '=' and '&')

Tags: wordpress, installation, menu, 4.7.10

Just updated to 4.7.10 on wordpress and any menu link with non alphanumeric characters is stripped and replaced by an underscore.

Example:
/civicrm/contact/add?reset=1&ct=Individual

Becomes:
civicrm/contact/add_reset_1_ct_Individual

I've tried clearing caches, rebuilding menus etc. Debugger shows nothing - any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is: bad upgrade from older database schema. Somewhere in the 4.5 alpha upgrade series something went wrong for me. I'm not sure what, exactly, but the answer was to verify the schema and to a clean install. Sad face.